# How can I move up by one element if element is not the parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have a structure like this

```
<ul>
  <li class="menu-parent">
    <ul class="tier-two">...</ul>
  </li>
  <div class="square"></div>


  <li class="menu-parent">
    <ul class="tier-two">...</ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I want is to have an event-handler that when I click on `div.square` shows the `ul.tier-two` in front of it. I have tried to use `closest()` but somehow it's not working.

Comment: Firstly you have invalid HTML, secondly closest is UP the DOM,  prev()/next() is sibling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("div.square").on("click", function(){
  $(this).next("li.menu-parent").find("ul.tier-two").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$('.square').prev('li').find('ul.tier-two')` with jQuery if you want.

hope it helps.